# Java - Bit Manipulation Acting Strange

Tags: java, image-processing, byte, bit

I currently have the simple function

```
public static void convert() {
     for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
         byteArray[i] = (byte) (byteArray[i] & ~(1 << 0));

         String s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & byteArray[i])).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
         System.out.println(s);
     }
}
```

which steps through an array of bytes and modifies each of the bits. This outputs the following:

```
11110110
11000010
11111010
```

**Where it gets strange however is when I add a simple if statement (that doesn't change anything) around the lines in the function, the output completely changes. For example, if I change the above function to**

```
public static void convert() {
     for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {

        if (5 > 3) {
         byteArray[i] = (byte) (byteArray[i] & ~(1 << 0));

         String s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & byteArray[i])).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
         System.out.println(s);
        }
     }
}
```

it outputs the following instead:

```
10100110
00011000
00010100
```

I am really confused as to why this is happening. Thanks.

The whole class just for reference:

```
public class LIB {
static byte[] byteArray;
static ArrayList<String> bitArray = new ArrayList<String>();
static String messageToDecode = "001010110";
static char[] mtdChar = messageToDecode.toCharArray();
static ArrayList<String> FinalBitArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    imageToBits();
    convert();

}

public static void imageToBits () throws IOException {
    //get image bytes
    byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(new File("/Users/2020shatgiskessell/Desktop/url.jpg").toPath());
     for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {

         String s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & byteArray[i])).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
         bitArray.add(s);

     }
}


public static void convert() {
     for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {

        if (5 > 3) {
         byteArray[i] = (byte) (byteArray[i] & ~(1 << 0));

         String s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & byteArray[i])).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
         System.out.println(s);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You've asked us to debug your code for you, and you haven't even provided all the code. Put it in a debugger and figure out what statement doesn't do what you expect. Then delete this post, unless you need help understanding that statement.

Comment: @arcy I provided all of the code except for the main function, which simply calls the functions. I am not sure why this error is occurring which is why I am reaching out to the stack overflow community. The debugger gives no information as to why this is happening.

Comment: `my_string.substring(0, my_string.length() - 2) + "1";` is one way to get it done, probably not the best.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly the problem still persists when I did that

Comment: @StephaneHatgis-Kessell If your problem is to replace the right most character in the string with a 1 then the code I provided works.

Comment: @StephaneHatgis-Kessell Debuggers give you the information that you look at, so you need to look at the right place. Every time you do a calculation or a string manipulation, you expect a particular result. Which of your statements produces results that you do not expect. Currently you know the whole program doesn't, so narrow it down - step through it, examining results at each statement. Either you'll figure out what's wrong, or you will encounter something that enables you to ask a question other than "Why doesn't this (incomplete) code work?"

Comment: Also, please adhere to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @arcy I used a debugger, narrowed down the problem, and have changed the question to better reflect this since I still am completely lost in the dark on this one. I would really appreciate if you took another look at it, thanks.

Comment: @StephaneHatgis-Kessell This program reads a file I do not have; I cannot debug it for you. Performing an `&` function on a byte with 0xff yields the byte unchanged. I have NO idea what `replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1")` does. `(byte) (byteArray[i] & ~(1 << 0))` looks to force the least sig bit to 0. In the debugger, examine the value of the byte array you are manipulating before you change it and after each change; if there is a manipulation of one value to another that you need explained, then give us the input, the output, and the expected output, and describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: @arcy The desired output for the input `11110111, 11000011, 11111010` is supposed to be `11110110, 11000010, 11111010`, because the line `("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & byteArray[i])).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");` replaces the rightmost bit value with zero for each byte. This works fine, however when an if statment is added, even if it does absolutely nothing, (as shown in the question), the output for some reason becomes `10100110, 00011000, 00010100`

Comment: This sounds to me like an April's fool day joke.

Answer (score 2):

I'm beginning to wonder about the April Fool's Day joke that @LittleSanti mentioned. If so, it's mean.

I wrote the following; I eliminated the assignment back into the source array, and put the 'strange behavior' condition within the loop instead of making it two separate runs so that we could see the results more easily. There isn't any such strange behavior in the (admittedly strange) expressions you have here.

```
package bitplay;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bitplay
{
//    public class LIB {
    static byte[] byteArray;
    static ArrayList<String> bitArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String messageToDecode = "001010110";
    static char[] mtdChar = messageToDecode.toCharArray();
    static ArrayList<String> FinalBitArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
      fakeRoutine();
    }

    private static void fakeRoutine()
    {
      byte[] array = new byte[] { (byte)0b11110111, 
                                  (byte)0b11000011,
                                  (byte)0b11111010 
                                };
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
      {
        String s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & array[i])).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
        System.out.println("1: " + s);

        byte clearedOne = (byte) (array[i] & ~(1 << 0));
        s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & clearedOne)).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
        System.out.println("2: " + s);

        if (5 > 3)
        {
          clearedOne = (byte) (array[i] & ~(1 << 0));
          s = ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & clearedOne)).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
          System.out.println("3: " + s);
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Absent any simultaneous alteration of the array somewhere else, the only other explanation that comes to my mind for the difference in output is a difference in input, and I cannot help you there.

The output I get from the above is:

```
1: 11110111
2: 11110110
3: 11110110
1: 11000011
2: 11000010
3: 11000010
1: 11111010
2: 11111010
3: 11111010
```

as expected. If you ever come up with a more specific question, go ahead and ask it, but I'm done with this question.